# Fabric2 CLI: gracefully switch SSH user

Tags: python, invoke, fabric

I am using Invoke/Fabric with boto3 to create an AWS instance and hand it over to an Ansible script. In order to do that, a few things have to be prepared on the remote machine before Ansible can take over, notably installing Python, create a user, and copy public SSH keys.

The AWS image comes with a particular user. I would like to use this user only to create my own user, copy public keys, and remove password login afterwards. While using the Fabric CLI the connection object is not created and cannot be modified within tasks.

What would be a good way to switch users (aka recreate a connection object between tasks) and run the following tasks with the user that I just created?

I might not go about it the right way (I am migrating from Fabric 1 where a switch of the env values has been sufficient). Here are a few strategies I am aware of, most of them remove some flexibility we have been relying on.

1. Create a custom AMI on which all preparations has been done already.
2. Create a local Connection object within a task for the user setup before falling back to the connection object provided by the Fabric CLI.
3. Deeper integrate AWS with Ansible (the problem is that we have users that might use Ansible after the instance is alive but don't have AWS privileges).

I guess this list includes also a best practice question.

Comment: Why not use AWS user data?  But, that said, you can change the env at run time so long as you call your subsequent tasks with `execute`.

Answer (score 0):

> The AWS image comes with a particular user. I would like to use this user 
>   only to create my own user, copy public keys, and remove password login 
>   afterwards. While using the Fabric CLI the connection object is not created 
>   and cannot be modified within tasks.

I'm not sure this is accurate.  I have switched users during the execution of a task just fine.  You just have to make sure that all subsequent calls that need the updated env use the `execute` operation.

e.g.

```
def create_users():
    run('some command')

def some_other_stuff():
    run('whoami')

@task
def new_instance():
    # provision instance using boto3
    env.host = [ ip_address ]
    env.user = 'ec2-user'
    env.password = 'sesame'
    execute(create_users)
    env.user = 'some-other-user'
    execute(some_other_stuff)
```

Comment: This is the Fabric 1 solution, I have been using, however Fabric 2 works with a connection object that cannot be modified within a task. Sorry for not making that clearer.